# Facing Connectivity Issues with Data Center on Ubuntu

Tags: software-center

I've been encountering some connectivity problems lately on AskUbuntu, specifically related to the data center. It seems that there might be some issues with accessing certain features or loading pages promptly.

Has anyone else experienced similar problems while using AskUbuntu? I've noticed sporadic delays in accessing the site and sometimes even timeouts when trying to interact with certain sections.

**Model:-** ThinkCentre M80q [Data Center](https://www.lenovo.com/ch/de/servers-storage/)

Could it possibly be a data center-related issue? Any insights or suggestions on how to potentially resolve or mitigate this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
Abhraham denis